# Using Brick or a Procedural texture to shade a chess board

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor

A beginner here, hi!

I'd like to create a chess scene, done modelling everything, although have a question with the board itself. 
I know that there are much easier ways to achieve it but for the sake of learning procedural texture, I wanted to create it with brick texture.
Here are some screenshots;[image]

[image]

But, I'm stuck. So, is it possible, am I stalling my learning process and probably you as well xd? How can I change this randomness? 
Thank you very much.

---

Ge, thanks for your answers.
Here is the result, my first non-follow along tutorial render ever. 
[image]

Comment: I think you are looking for the Checker texture instead

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use a checker texture (Or use [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/173379/86891) to modify the bias in the brick texture to behave like a checker) and darken the color with the black outline of the brick texture afterwards :

[image]

Note : The scale of the checker texture must be 2 * that of the brick texture, otherwise the edges won't align.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the *Bias input*, and as @Gorgious suggested, a *Map Range* node.

1. Set *Brick height/width* to 1, so it matches the Checker texture
2. Add *Checker texture* and *Map Range* node with *To min* set to -1.
3. Use *Mapping node* to scale both textures to 8

[image]

[image]

Comment: Alright ! Thanks for elaborating on this ! Alternatively to the Mix RGB node, you can use a "Map Range" Node (Requires Blender 2.81+) with the "To Min" input set to -1. Then you don't have to add value nodes to set the boundaries. Cheers

Comment: Thanks a lot :). I felt there's a more elegant solution.